# How to align loading icon at center horizontally in PagedGridView?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, infinite-scroll

I am trying to display the news items in PagedGridView using infinite scrolling for loading finite amount of data at a time. Everything is working fine, but I got stuck in managing alignment of loading indicator while fetching additional data. The loading icon is aligned to right while I want it to be at center of screen horizontally.[image]

```
PagedGridView(
                    pagingController: _pagingController,
                    scrollController: _scrollController,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        childAspectRatio: 5.2 / 8.0,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
                        mainAxisExtent: 225),
                    builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Post>(
                        itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                            return AllNewsCard(
                                allNews:
                                newsHeadlineController.getAllNewsList[index]);
                         
                    }),
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the loading indicator as a grid item. That's why it's positioned on the right.
I would use `CustomScrollView` with `SliverGrid` instead of `PagedGridView` and `SliverFillRemaining` for displaying an activity indicator.

```dart
  CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverGrid(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return AllNewsCard(
              allNews: newsHeadlineController.getAllNewsList[index]);
        }),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          childAspectRatio: 5.2 / 8.0,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
          mainAxisExtent: 225,
        ),
      ),
      if (isLoading)
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: false,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: it's giving me error as The argument type 'PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Post>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SliverChildDelegate'.

Comment: this solution doesn't work as it gives the error in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

In `PagedGridView` add `showNewPageProgressIndicatorAsGridChild: false`

like this:

```
PagedGridView(
        showNewPageProgressIndicatorAsGridChild: false,
        ....
```

this will make the `PagedGridView` to not treat the loading indicator as grid item.